# Show number of notifications on icon

Tags: html, css, css-position, font-awesome

I have a notification icon ([font-awesome](/questions/tagged/font-awesome)) which shows the number of notifications.

I am having a problem trying to get the number to display in the correct position, as shown in see below image

[image]

I need the text to be smaller and move right and up a little...
here is the code

```
.header .bubble {
  border-radius: 100%;
  height: 14px;
  width: 14px;
  background-color: rgba(226, 32, 91, 0.77);
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: top;
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  float: right;
  right: -3px;
}

 <a href="javascript:;" id="notification-center" class="icon-set globe-fill" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="bubble">2</span>
```

Can anyone help, I am new to this.

Comment: Why do the header and bubble have same css properties? You should separete this making header relative and your number absolute within the relative

Comment: They don't have the same properties. .header .bubble.. not .header, .bubble..

Comment: Can you please make a fiddle ? Or at least give us your markup

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q84ydjr0/

Answer (score 33, accepted):

#### example1: using background image

The best way to do this is to use `position:absolute` to child span of parent anchor.

```css
a.notif {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/evpC48G.png');
  background-size: contain;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.num {
  position: absolute;
  right: 11px;
  top: 6px;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<a href="" class="notif"><span class="num">2</span></a>
```

#### example2: using font awesome icon

If you want to use [font-awesome](/questions/tagged/font-awesome) icon

this is code for it

```css
a.fa-globe {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: grey;
  cursor: pointer;
}
span.fa-comment {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0.6em;
  top: -4px;
  color: red;
  right: -4px;
}
span.num {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 0.3em;
  top: 1px;
  color: #fff;
  right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<a class="fa fa-globe">
  <span class="fa fa-comment"></span>
  <span class="num">2</span>
</a>
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you, how would I change the image to an icon? (`<i class="fa fa-globe"></i>`)

Comment: you can apply position relative to that icon and do this same

Comment: And how do I make the red text box wider?

Comment: wait making solution of for your icon